# Django tests: where to put a simple test that a page contains content?

Tags: django

This is an embarrassingly simple question, but working in Django 1.8, what's the best way to write a test that a web page has rendered and has some text in it?

I already have simple tests for my views that check the status code and the template used:

```
def test_call_view_bnf_section(self):
    response = self.client.get('/bnf/0202')
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
    self.assertTemplateUsed(response, 'bnf_section.html')
```

Now I'd like to check, for example, that the text 'BNF Section' is present inside an `<h1>` tag.

How can I do this? And are these view tests the best place to do that, or should I be writing functional tests using Selenium instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this particular test you can add:

```
self.assertContains(response, '<h1>BNF Section</h1>')
```

More in Django Documentation: [Writing and running tests](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/testing/overview/#module-django.test) and [SimpleTestCase.assertContains](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.SimpleTestCase.assertContains)

This is an easy test and no need to get involved with Selenium, at least for this.